# How to simulate a PC speaker?

Tags: audio, kernel-modules, alsa

I bought a modern laptop which seems to lack a hardware speaker. Is there some kernel module to simulate it over ALSA instead or so? I could find only some very old patched modules from late 90s which barely work on modern kernel versions already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same sort of problem with a cheap amd mini pc. I am getting old and my eyesight is poor so I like the beep when editing or using a terminal. When I snooze onto the keyboard the beeping can wake me :)

After discussion with bodqhrohro he suggested I should answer his question here. I found two solutions, but neither is perfect.

I searched for a way to get beeping back.  Lennart Poettering wrote softbeep in 2002 using an LD_PRELOAD approach. I tried and it didn't work well for me.

I then found https://github.com/mozzwald/Fancy-Beeper-Daemon and after patching and testing wrote an arch linux AUR to build it as a dkms module.
https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/fancybeep-dkms
I added a simple alsa beep program to create a reasonable beep. This approach works, but because the daemon hangs on one of the module created devices (/dev/beep) modprobe -r fancybeep fails because the module is busy. So you have to kill the userspace beep daemon first.

I changed the daemon to beep when signalled with SIGUSR1 and eliminated the extra device /dev/beep. The module has a parameter that the daemon can post its PID to.  The module can then just signal the daemon when it wants a beep to be sounded. This approach https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/alsabeep-dkms also works, but obvously is a bit unsafe as if the daemon is killed without clearing the module's PID parameter the module is left signalling a PID that is out of date and could be a future problem.

I imagine the correct approach would be a module that starts off the daemon directly it could either obtain the PID and use a signal or use netlink to request a beep. I'm not enough of a kernel person to figure out exactly how to do that.